# PCA results on imbalanced data with duplicates

Tags: statistics, pca, variance

I am using sklearn IPCA decomposition and surprised that if I delete duplicates from my dataset, the result differs from the "unclean" one.

What is the reason? As I think, the variance is the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *programming* questions; please consider posting this to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. But on top of this, the exact meaning of "the result differs" is arguably unclear...

Comment: @desertnaut I did it but here I received minus in my reputation

Comment: Just delete the post, and the minus will go away along with it...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. The duplicates from the dataset change the variance.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/381983/230117